# ESP8266: Send beacon frame with deep sleep mode does not work properly

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, beacon

I have a problem with my esp8266 project. My purpose is to use esp8266 to transmit beacon frames every one second so that my android device or my laptop can receive it and display in list of APs which i can connect to.
Here is my code I wrote:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
extern "C" {
  #include "user_interface.h"
}

void setup() {
  delay(500);
  sendBeacon("ESP8266");
  ESP.deepSleep(10e5);
}

void loop() {
}

void sendBeacon(char* ssid) {
    // Randomize channel //
    byte channel = 1; 
    wifi_set_channel(channel);

    uint8_t packet[128] = { 0x80, 0x00, //Frame Control 
                        0x00, 0x00, //Duration
                /*4*/   0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, //Destination address 
                /*10*/  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, //Source address - overwritten later
                /*16*/  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, //BSSID - overwritten to the same as the source address
                /*22*/  0xc0, 0x6c, //Seq-ctl
                //Frame body starts here
                /*24*/  0x83, 0x51, 0xf7, 0x8f, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //timestamp - the number of microseconds the AP has been active
                /*32*/  0xFF, 0x00, //Beacon interval
                /*34*/  0x01, 0x04, //Capability info
                /* SSID */
                /*36*/  0x00
                };

    int ssidLen = strlen(ssid);
    packet[37] = ssidLen;

    for(int i = 0; i < ssidLen; i++) {
      packet[38+i] = ssid[i];
    }

    uint8_t postSSID[13] = {0x01, 0x08, 0x82, 0x84, 0x8b, 0x96, 0x24, 0x30, 0x48, 0x6c, //supported rate
                        0x03, 0x01, 0x04 /*DSSS (Current Channel)*/ };

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      packet[38 + ssidLen + i] = postSSID[i];
    }

    packet[50 + ssidLen] = channel;

    // get SRC MAC
    unsigned char mac[6];
    WiFi.macAddress(mac);
    packet[10] = packet[16] = mac[0];
    packet[11] = packet[17] = mac[1];
    packet[12] = packet[18] = mac[2];
    packet[13] = packet[19] = mac[3];
    packet[14] = packet[20] = mac[4];
    packet[15] = packet[21] = mac[5];

    int packetSize = 51 + ssidLen;

    wifi_send_pkt_freedom(packet, packetSize, 0);
    delay(1);
}
```

I used tcpdump to capture those frame and yes, they are there. But I still couldn't see it in list of AP on my laptop and my android device.
I can see it if I stop using deep sleep mode. For example:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
extern "C" {
  #include "user_interface.h"
}

void setup() {
  delay(500);
//  sendBeacon("ESP8266");
//  ESP.deepSleep(10e5);
}

void loop() {
  sendBeacon("ESP8266");
}

void sendBeacon(char* ssid) {
    // Randomize channel //
    byte channel = 1; 
    wifi_set_channel(channel);

    uint8_t packet[128] = { 0x80, 0x00, //Frame Control 
                        0x00, 0x00, //Duration
                /*4*/   0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, //Destination address 
                /*10*/  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, //Source address - overwritten later
                /*16*/  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, //BSSID - overwritten to the same as the source address
                /*22*/  0xc0, 0x6c, //Seq-ctl
                //Frame body starts here
                /*24*/  0x83, 0x51, 0xf7, 0x8f, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //timestamp - the number of microseconds the AP has been active
                /*32*/  0xFF, 0x00, //Beacon interval
                /*34*/  0x01, 0x04, //Capability info
                /* SSID */
                /*36*/  0x00
                };

    int ssidLen = strlen(ssid);
    packet[37] = ssidLen;

    for(int i = 0; i < ssidLen; i++) {
      packet[38+i] = ssid[i];
    }

    uint8_t postSSID[13] = {0x01, 0x08, 0x82, 0x84, 0x8b, 0x96, 0x24, 0x30, 0x48, 0x6c, //supported rate
                        0x03, 0x01, 0x04 /*DSSS (Current Channel)*/ };

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      packet[38 + ssidLen + i] = postSSID[i];
    }

    packet[50 + ssidLen] = channel;

    // get SRC MAC
    unsigned char mac[6];
    WiFi.macAddress(mac);
    packet[10] = packet[16] = mac[0];
    packet[11] = packet[17] = mac[1];
    packet[12] = packet[18] = mac[2];
    packet[13] = packet[19] = mac[3];
    packet[14] = packet[20] = mac[4];
    packet[15] = packet[21] = mac[5];

    int packetSize = 51 + ssidLen;

    wifi_send_pkt_freedom(packet, packetSize, 0);
    delay(1);
}
```

Does anyone know why? Please help me to get this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ESP.deepSleep(10e5) makes the processor sleep for 100ms, not a second. The correct would be ESP.deepSleep(10e6). Secondly, you are trying to send just one packet every second or so, it's quite hard to make sure that the wifi reading from the device is gonna get that packet for sure and display it on the list of SSIDs. From my experiments, I had to send three packets every 200ms to make sure it was displayed on my android mobile and pc. You can try to play with the number of packets you send and the interval to see what fits you best...

Also, make sure to configure the ESP correctly at the setup function. When I tried my similar code I had to use two instructions: wifi_set_opmode(STATION_MODE) and wifi_promiscuous_enable(1)